# Extract the diagonal of a data

Tags: bash

I would like to extract the diagonal of a data which appears like a square matrix thanks to bash.

The data is :

```
 0.65603 -0.41101  0.17555  0.07549 -0.18749  0.07549  0.17555 -0.41101
-0.41101  0.72255 -0.65014  0.25679  0.13301 -0.24321  0.05697  0.22255
 0.17555 -0.65014  0.80380 -0.59262  0.20108  0.11449 -0.19620  0.05697
 0.07549  0.25679 -0.59262  0.74808 -0.61115  0.24808  0.11449 -0.24321
-0.18749  0.13301  0.20108 -0.61115  0.79509 -0.61115  0.20108  0.13301
 0.07549 -0.24321  0.11449  0.24808 -0.61115  0.74808 -0.59262  0.25679
 0.17555  0.05697 -0.19620  0.11449  0.20108 -0.59262  0.80380 -0.65014
-0.41101  0.22255  0.05697 -0.24321  0.13301  0.25679 -0.65014  0.72255
Point group blocks [8]
 2.00000
 1.99989
 1.74085
 0.25904
 0.00022
 0.00000
 0.00000
 0.00000
```

I don't care about what is after "Point group blocks", I just need the diagonal of the square matrix. I think I have to do something like grep the n-th chain of character in the n-th line, but I don't know how to do this... For the first line, I just do :

```
value=`grep '' data`
value1=`echo "${value:0:8}"  | bc -l`
```

Is this is only for the first value of course... Is there a general way to grep each diagonal value of any square data?

Edit : if we look at the answer on the duplicate topic, it should be in my case :

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) if (NR >= 1 && NR == i) print $(i) }' file.txt
```

And in the case we want to add the numerous of the line :

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) if (NR >= 1 && NR == i) print i,$(i) }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is the correct tool.

```
awk '/Point/{exit 0} {print $NR}' file.txt
```

The script stops if it encounters the first line with 'Point' in it. For all lines before it prints the field which is equal to the line number.